# I am always getting the last result

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

```
var dataObj:any={};
var details:any=[];

for (var i=0;i<this.state.handleLeaveCancel.length;i++){
  dataObj["leaveRequestId"]=this.state.handleLeaveCancel[i]
  dataObj["status"]=-1
  details.push(dataObj)
} 
console.log(details)
```

Comment: Can you give us more clarity?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `var dataObj:any={};` inside your loop

```
var details:any=[];

for (var i=0;i<this.state.handleLeaveCancel.length;i++){
  var dataObj:any={};
  dataObj["leaveRequestId"]=this.state.handleLeaveCancel[i]
  dataObj["status"]=-1
  details.push(dataObj)
} 
console.log(details)
```